# Fastest Way to Multiply Dictionary Values and Output to 'list type'

Tags: python, list, optimization, dictionary, numpy

I have two dictionaries with the same keys but different values.  I want to perform an operation that combines the two and then creates a 'list type' object of them in no specific order.  I am going to be doing this on large datasets so speed is a priority.  What is the fastest way of doing this?

So far I have these ideas.  I am new to python so I don't know much about how each function operates but I am assuming option 2 is the fastest.  Are there faster methods?

```
mydict = {"cats":1,"dog":3,"bird":2,"wolves":10}
exp = {"cats":10,"dog":23,"bird":34,"wolves":43}

#Option 1
mydict.update((x, y**(exp[x])) for x, y in mydict.items())
items = mydict.values()

#Option 2          // I think this is currently the fastest
items = []
items.append(y**(exp[x]) for x,y in mydict.items())

#Option 3
items = numpy.array(len(mydict))
for x,y in mydict:
    items[?] = y**(exp[x])     // Is there a way to do this? Maybe with a counter
```

Comment: why are you worried about fastest?

Comment: I am working with very large dictionaries (>10,000).  I also always try making the fastest/cleanest code possible out of habit.

Comment: 10**423 exceeds the largest int representable as an integer (or float) NumPy dtype, so there is no point in using NumPy here: `np.iinfo('int64').max < 10**423`. (You could use `object` dtype, but there is no speed benefit in that case.)

Comment: I typed completely random numbers in.  In reality the numbers will be fractionally small.  I edited my question to adjust my numbers.

Comment: How small are they? `np.iinfo('int64').max < 10**19`, so your edited example remains too large for NumPy, if you want integer precision.

Comment: Do they really need to be dictionaries? Are you really accessing a 10,000+ dict with keys other than natural numbers? Could three 10,000+ item arrays (one for the keys, and one for the values of each of your current dictionaries) replace your current two dictionaries? If you are going to do math like this often, redoing your code may be a better option.

Comment: My bad.  They will be around e-8 at the smallest.  Probably larger after the math operations.

Comment: Option 2 is fastest because it's wrong. It's not actually doing the math; it's appending a generator to the list.

Comment: @Jaime I am parsing two unsorted documents.  I chose dictionaries because it would be easier than sorting them into arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
[mydict[key]**exp[key] for key in mydict.keys()]
```

assuming mydict and exp both have the exact same keys?

Side note:

```
[mydict[key]**exp[key] for key in mydict]
```

does the same thing as above, the `.keys()` is optional.

And if you're concerned with speed use the time module to test the speed of each method as such:

```
import time
t = time.clock()
for i in range(1000):
    # your code here, for example:
    [mydict[key]**exp[key] for key in mydict.keys()]
print "time", time.clock() - t
```

Comment: This definitely looks better than my examples.  I had a feeling there was a better way of doing this in one step.

Comment: Sorry, I was just waiting for my test to finish.  Yours was slightly faster than my option 2 and 3x faster than my option 1.